# Get count from has many relationship from 3 models

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I have 3 models.

1. `Company`
2. `Product`
3. `Offer`

A `Company` has many `Products`.
A `Product` has many `Offers`.

How can I get the number/count of `Offers` a `Company` has?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following:

```
Offer::whereHas('product', function($query) use ($company_id) {
    $query->where('company_id', $company_id);
})->count();
```

`Offer` model should contain `product` relation that return the `Product` model of the `Offer`

Answer (score 0):

Join the tables together and then find the count of each company:

```
DB::table('Company')
->join('Product', 'Company.product_id', '=', 'Company.id')
->join('Offer', 'Product.offer_id', '=', 'Offer.id')
->select('Company.id', 'Company.name', DB::raw("count(*) AS num_offers"))
->groupBy('Company.id')   // could also group by Company.name, but may not need it
->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a Laravel way of doing the same?

Comment: @FelipePeña This _is_ Laravel code.  Are you joking with me?

Comment: Tim, what I meant is having this with hasMany or belongsToMany instructions. In a more simplified way.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem in many projects. You can try this

```
$Companies = Company::where('id',$company_id)->whereHas('product', function($query) {
    $query->with('offers');
})->get();
```

so you will get $Companies as a array. loop that then you will get all companies with their products and offers `$Companies[]->product[]->offers[]->count();`

as a single object `$Company->product->offer->count();`